# How to fix bathroom tiles falling off

Tags: bathroom, tiling

This happened in my bathroom just now.

The build got completed approx 12 months ago and now tiles are coming off this extended wall.

During construction, the builders told me, that the bathtub didn't fill out the length of the room. So they wanted to "pad" the adjacent wall a few inches so it didn't leave a gap. At the time it seemed sensible. In hindsight, it was a terrible idea. I'm sure there would have been better solutions for this little problem.

How can I best recover from this?
And what did the builders do wrong?

[image]

**EDIT**

I contacted the builder and they ended up demolishing the entire bathroom, including knocking down ALL of the tiles. It comes with a 5 year warranty so I walk away scot-free.

For the wall that needs to come out a few inches extra (in the picture), they are using metal studs and Villaboard which is all drilled deep into the wall with plugs and screws. Then tiling goes on top, this time no five spotting but applying the tile glue the right way covering 90% of the tile. Also they are re-doing the waterproofing.

Comment: You don't indicate where in the world you are, but many new homes in the US come with a "warranty" - this seems like an _ideal_ time to file a claim if you've got one! As jwh20 pointed out in his answer, this will need to be completely torn out and redone.

Comment: Rent a billboard, put this picture and the name of the company that did the work on it, and wait. Or call them and *threaten to do that.* This assumes the idiots are still in business, which might be false with that quality of work. You could start with whatever free electronic posting services are specific to your area...

Comment: I'll give 'em credit: That's very _creative_. It's not quality. It's not anywhere _near_ the way it should be done, but it is _creative_. A solid `B-` for outside the box thinking. A very strong `F`, though, for quality and integrity.

Comment: Can you tell what they used to bind the tiles?   From the pictures it sure seems like joint compound!!

Comment: Holy smoke, I'd keep a towel lain there, so falling tiles don't crack the floor tile!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica What makes you think the floor tile shouldn't be ripped out and replaced too?  I wouldn't be too precious about anything in that room.  I think the whole thing needs a sledgehammer taken to it.

Comment: Oddly, it looks like the architect left exactly enough room for furring strips and a sheet of cement board there.  Why on earth they decided to use hellishly expensive tile and compound to fill the gap, who knows?  Maybe they ran out of tropical hardwood...

Comment: It takes real expertise to do a job that badly.  I mean I've done exactly 2 tiling jobs, and slowly, perhaps a touch unevenly, but at least they stayed on the wall (and had proper tile adhesive all over the backs).  Those were pretty much just held in with the grout.

Comment: @J... May have been spares :-)

Comment: @Mast Hah, yeah... why buy one when you can buy two for twice the price.

Comment: I'd find out who the contractor is, it's clearly a scam. with emails these days you can always find a company after it's done a job, and that is hiding a "fake job" that was never completed properly.

Comment: On the bright side you can probably pop the remaining tiles off by hand and reuse them -- the binding material shouldn't be hard to scrape off.

Comment: This belongs to law@stackexchange.com . There's really nothing else to do here than tear down, rebuild and sue the contractors. Even a full refund would be short of addressing the risks you took: getting knocked by a falling tile and drowning in the bathtub.

Comment: I don't know why my suggestion to use duct tape was deleted.  After all, it's no worse than the original technique.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to figure out from the photo but it appears that they stuck scraps of tile to the wall with compound and then simply stuck the finish tiles to that with more compound.  NOT A GOOD PLAN!  The finish tiles are poorly supported and also the smooth surface of the scraps doesn't provide good adhesion for the compound.

This is a total tear-out job if ever I've seen one!  I don't see how you're going to salvage any part of this and I'd also be concerned about substandard work on the rest of the job.

Comment: I'd suggest also insisting that the tile on the other walls be torn out to ensure something shifty/shoddy like this wasn't done there, too.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm not sure I'd allow a contractor who did this kind of shoddy work on my property again.

Comment: I didn't suggest that the original contractor do the work, just that the other walls be redone, just to be sure they don't have similar (or very different) corner cutting.

Comment: @jwh20 I don't think anyone suggested using the same contractor again!  But any other work they did should also be assumed to be defective and in needing of replacement.

Comment: I felt that the "insisting that the tile..." phrase meant the original contractor.  A responsible contractor would not have to be "encouraged" to tear the whole mess out.  In my experience someone who does stuff like shown in the photo will do it incorrectly as a matter of practice.

Comment: Well the biggest issue is what you call a "compound" isn't the right material for tile.   The prep of the wall being done incorrectly and the installation is secondary.   So you are right in your conclusion but the main reason that the home owner has to redo everything is that the binding material is wrong.   The rest if prepped better will stay up longer but eventually fail for the same reason.

Comment: I call it "compound" because I cannot tell what it is from the photo.  It's some sort of "compound" but even if the "right" stuff had been used, I don't see how it would have stayed put.  Bottom line is that this is a VERY poor job of tile installation.

Answer (score 30):

You don't "pad out" a wall and then tile it. They had a couple of inches to work with. So stud the wall with 2x2 or 2x4's flat and cover with cement board, waterproof, then tile. It probably would have been faster than what they did.

You're going to have to remove all of that wall and redo it.

Comment: And, as pointed out in a comment to another question, the rest of the walls too - just to be safe.

Comment: There's some really nice foam-cored cement-faced board used in wet rooms here in the UK.  It comes in a variety of thicknesses and is meant for just this sort of thing

Answer (score 20):

Regarding the gap, baths almost never fit the space exactly.  Apart from the obvious problem of building and preparing walls millimetre-accurately, if the bath fits the space too closely then you're going to have extreme difficulty actually getting it in there.  Pythagoras says that dropping the bath in anything less than perfectly parallel will make the bath take up more length than there is space for, so it'll jam partway down.  The result on an acrylic bath will likely be damage to the bath rim.

it is entirely normal to fix a batten along the end wall to fit the gap (normally at the non-tap end), and cut tiles to fit over that.  The tiles here could be round-edged (trim) tiles, or they could be normal tiles with a trim strip to finish them.  The tiles should have a slight slope towards the bath so that splashes will drain back, but they should be flat enough that this is a good place to put soap, shampoos and so on.  If the gap is small enough then just a trim strip may be sufficient.

Or as JACK says, finish the wall accurately with an appropriate type of drywall, and tile on that.  If you want to pack the wall out, that's the right way to do it.

When you agreed to it as a solution, it **was** sensible.  Don't blame yourself on this one.  The problem isn't you agreeing to it, the problem is simply the half-assed way they've gone about it.

Comment: +1 to your last sentence especially.

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with some of the reasoning of the other answers.

1. **They should have furred out the wall.**   Everyone here agrees on this.   They could have framed out more or just added shims/drywall layer... lots of methods here depending on how far you go out.
2. Point that no one has brought up.   Most bathrooms - normal ones - not the fit-for-a-king master... they are basically **built around the tub or shower pan**.   Yours fits that bill.   Why the hell would they even frame the bathroom without the specifications or the tub onsite.   That is f'ing crazy and amateur amateur.   Who was the general contractor and were they overseeing anything??   I would be worried about the entire house honestly.
3. That is not a flat/proper substrate to attach things to.   You can't just put tile on anything!!!
4. I am not sure what the material is but it isn't thinset and if it is mastic it is a really cheap type.   **"Stuff" that you use to install tiles sticks to the tile**.   It doesn't bind to itself more and form cow patties.   The binding material is "who-knows" but way way off.   ***No matter what this stuff was going to fall down.***   That is given the first three points were done right.
5. These are large large tiles.   To install them properly (with thinset or similar material) **you would back butter each piece and apply/trowel the thinset to the wall**.   The installer plopped a few big drops on each tile and stuck it on the wall.   Even if steps 1-4 were done right the tiles would fall off.

So yea you have to take down the whole bathtub area.   Even given that things 1-3 may not apply to the rest of the area, #4 and #5 will and these tiles will fall off too.   **The good thing is there is a high chance you can reuse these tiles if the rest were done the same way.**

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR

Five-spotting is a really bad practice.

Per https://www.daltile.com/how-to/how-to-install-tile/how-to-install-large-format-tile:

> When installing large format tile, there must be at least 90% mortar contact

---

It is hard to say whether the compound they used was mortar so I am not going to gripe about that.

The fact that they should have furred out the wall has already been covered in other answers.

What I want to concentrate on is making you aware of the technique which they employed to put the tiles up and it's called [five-spotting](https://www.ceramictilefoundation.org/blog/eliminate-spot-bonding-ceramic-tile-installation). An utterly heinous method used by sub-par contractors. Even if the correct compound and furring was used you would still have been prone to this tile issue because they severely cut corners with your install.

Assuming that the walls and floors were done by the same contractor then all of the tile work **NEEDS** to be ripped out because I am 99.99567% positive that five-spotting was used for everything. Right now you are pitted against a neverending slew of tiles falling off the wall and possibly hurting someone, and your floor should start showing defects as well if it already hasn't.

Comment: This job is MUCH worse than what you're describing.